# function/transformation of a random variable in the context of parametric degradation reliability

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, derived-distributions

Working on a reliability project and ran across this problem of parametric degradation over time relative to a failure threshold.

Need to calculate the distribution of failure times $t_{f,i}$ for a set of devices  $i=1...N $ where failure is defined parametrically as $|S_{i}(t)|\ge S_{f}$ and failure times per device as $|S_{i}(t_{f,i})|=S_f$ where $S_{i}(t) = A_{i} \ln (1+bt)$ and $\{S_{i}(t_1)\}$ , at a time $t=t_1<t_{f,i}$ for all $i$, is Gaussian distributed with mean $\mu $ and standard deviation $\sigma $, i.e. $N(\mu,\sigma).$

[image]

In contrast, it is relatively easy to show that if instead the degradation path were a simple power law, $S_{i}(t)=A_{i}t^{n}$ that the resultant failure time distribution is lognormal with log-mean $\ln t_{1} + \frac{1}{n}\ln(\frac{S_{f}}{\mu})$ and log-standard deviation $\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+\frac{\sigma}{\mu})$

Comment: Just to clarify - if $S_i(t_1)$ is random, then one or both of $A_i$ and $b$ are random.  Which is it, or is there something else going on?

Comment: correct ... I've indexed $A$ as $A_i $ since it is different for each device, but $b $ is the same for all devices ... the cases where both are indexed or only $b $ is are fair game as well

Comment: It looks like there's something missing after the last "where," but I can't figure out what it should be. Can you please edit for clarity?